# What is this Android folder icon with a small yellow circle in the lower right corner?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, icons

## Preface

This question is different from [What is this Android folder icon with a set of three vertical bars in the lower right corner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191119/what-is-this-android-folder-icon-with-a-set-of-three-vertical-bars-in-the-lower) because I am asking about a different icon.  I split these up into their own questions because of [this answer to a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314834/389623)

## Background

I am trying to find the formal name for this folder icon ([image]) that appears next to every **app** directory in Android.

I have looked in the following documentation:

1. The [IntelliJ icon reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html)
2. Under **Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > File Types** (on Mac)
3. Looking at the balloon for the folder when waving the mouse over it:

   [image]

None of these mention what the folder icon means or if they do they are not specific enough.

## Question

What is the name for ([image])?  Please provide documentation in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It denotes the [Android module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-android-development.html#addAndroidModule).

Comment: Which link inside the documentation explicitly describes that the icon is indeed the Android module?