# What is this Android folder icon with a set of three vertical bars in the lower right corner?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, icons

## Preface

This question is different from [What is this Android fodler icon with a small yellow circle in the lower right corner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190956/what-is-this-android-fodler-icon-with-a-small-yellow-circle-in-the-lower-right-c) because I am asking about a different icon.  I split these up into their own questions because of [this answer to a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314834/389623)

## Background

I am trying to find the formal name for this folder icon([image]) that appears next to what seems to be helper libraries.

I have looked in the following documentation:

1. The [IntelliJ Icon Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html)
2. Under **Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > File Types** (on Mac)
3. Looking at the balloon for the folder when waving the mouse over it:

   [image]

None of these mention what the folder icon means or if they do they are not specific enough.

## Question

What is the name for ([image])? Please provide documentation in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 'Library folder' icon denotes the [Project library.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-library-and-global-library-pages.html)